# parseInt() returns random values

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to do this simple parsing the text from span to integer then add one and return value to the text

```
    var count = parseInt($(".contact_unread_"+$from).text(),10) + 1;
    $(".contact_unread_"+$from).text(count);
```

but the result when calling the function 6 times  as follow and starting value is 0:

0 >>> 1

1 >>> 12

12 >>> 1213

1213 >>> 12131214

12131214 >>> 1213121412131215

1213121412131215 >>> 1.2131214121312151e+31

and I don't think I'm concatenating the values as strings or the output would be different.

function :

```
   function receiveMessage($from,$message) {
chatname = $("#chat").text(); 
if ($message !=""){
  if(chatname == $from){
      $(".msg_container_base").append('<div class="row msg_container base_receive"><div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2 avatar"><img src="http://www.bitrebels.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/Original-Facebook-Geek-Profile-Avatar-1.jpg" class=" img-responsive "></div><div class="col-md-10 col-xs-10"><div class="messages msg_receive"><p>'+$message+'</p><time datetime="2009-11-13T20:00">Timothy • 51 min</time></div></div></div>');
   }else{
   var count = parseInt($(".contact_unread_"+$from).text(),10) + 1;
    $(".contact_unread_"+$from).text(count);
   }
}
```

}

Comment: Please put an [mcve] in the question, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I added the full funciton

Comment: That's great, but it's not a [mcve], and neither is it runnable. Fortunately, I was able to figure out what was going on without, but for future, that's really the best thing to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`parseInt` doesn't behave chaotically.

Clearly you have two elements that match the selector you're using. `text` is unlike other jQuery accessors *(sigh)*: When you call it on multiple elements, it returns the text of **all** of them, not just the first like `html` and `attr` (and `prop` and `css` and ...) do.

So you're setting them both to 1 on your first pass, then getting back `"11"` which parses as 11 (+ 1 = 12), then getting back `"1212"` (+ 1 = 1213), etc.

Here's an example with two such elements:

```js
var $from = "x";
var timer = setInterval(function() {
  var count = parseInt($(".contact_unread_"+$from).text(),10) + 1;
  $(".contact_unread_"+$from).text(count);
  console.log("count = " + count);
}, 500);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("Stopping now");
  clearInterval(timer);
}, 5000);
```

```html
<div class="contact_unread_x">0</div>
<div class="contact_unread_x">0</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And the same example with just one:

```js
var $from = "x";
var timer = setInterval(function() {
  var count = parseInt($(".contact_unread_"+$from).text(),10) + 1;
  $(".contact_unread_"+$from).text(count);
  console.log("count = " + count);
}, 500);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("Stopping now");
  clearInterval(timer);
}, 5000);
```

```html
<div class="contact_unread_x">0</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: that is right there was another element , is there a way to choose one of them without going back to their parents ?

Comment: @Ahmedna: Sure -- [`first`](http://api.jquery.com/first/), [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/), [`eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/), [`:eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/), ...